# ManagementEventWatcher, process monitoring

Tags: c#

I'm using `ManagementEventWatcher` to monitoring some process. It works well but I think the code's kinda repetitive. I was wondering what would be the correct way for more than once single process, if I had more than two process it'd become a mess. Thanks!

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string tick = "0.1";
   string lcuProcess = "LeagueClientUx.exe";
   string gameProcess = "League of legends.exe";

   string lcuQuery = String.Format(@"
   SELECT * 
   FROM __InstanceOperationEvent 
   WITHIN {0} 
   WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' 
   AND TargetInstance.Name = '{1}'", tick, lcuProcess
   );

   string gameQuery = String.Format(@"
   SELECT * 
   FROM __InstanceOperationEvent 
   WITHIN {0} 
   WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' 
   AND TargetInstance.Name = '{1}'", tick, gameProcess
   );

   string scope = @"\\.\root\CIMV2";

   ManagementEventWatcher watcherLCU = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, lcuQuery);
   watcherLCU.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(OnEventArrived_lcu);
   watcherLCU.Start();

   ManagementEventWatcher watcherGame = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, gameQuery);
   watcherGame.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(OnEventArrived_game);
   watcherGame.Start();
}

private static void OnEventArrived_lcu(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
   // Do something...
}

private static void OnEventArrived_game(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
   // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
private async void Form1_Load
```

Why `async` without `await`? Remove `async`.

The query can be a constant like

```cs
const string queryPattern = @"
SELECT * 
FROM __InstanceOperationEvent 
WITHIN {0} 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' 
AND TargetInstance.Name = '{1}'";
```

Then you can reuse it multiple times.

But you may modify the query to catch event for both apps like

```cs
const string queryPattern = @"
SELECT * 
FROM __InstanceOperationEvent 
WITHIN {0} 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' 
AND (TargetInstance.Name = '{1}' OR TargetInstance.Name = '{2}')";
```

Also `Form_Load` handler can do multiple jobs. To avoid mixing code in one method, and improve readability, move the code to a separate method.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetupEventWatcher();
}

private void SetupEventWatcher()
{
    const string tick = "0.1";
    const string lcuProcess = "LeagueClientUx.exe";
    const string gameProcess = "League of legends.exe";
    const string queryPattern = @"
    SELECT * 
    FROM __InstanceOperationEvent 
    WITHIN {0} 
    WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' 
    AND (TargetInstance.Name = '{1}' OR TargetInstance.Name = '{2}')";

    string query = string.Format(queryPattern, tick, lcuProcess, gameProcess);
    string scope = @"\\.\root\CIMV2";

    ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
    watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(OnEventArrived);
    watcher.Start();
}

private static void OnEventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    // EventArrivedEventArgs can be helpful to determine which process caused the event to occur
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just one thing, at the moment I'm using `e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName.Contains("InstanceDeletionEvent")` and `e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName.Contains("InstanceCreationEvent")` to detect when the process is opened/closed. Now that I'm handling with two process in the same event who could I know what process is each? Thanks!

Comment: @Omar I didn't use WMI yet. Sorry. Probably [`Process.GetProcessesByName`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netcore-3.1) may help or something like that, in case `EventArrivedEventArgs` doesn't contain the required data.